# Why would lord Kalki accept an offering in which an animal is killed?

Tags: yajna, kalki, kalki-purana

In the Kalki Purana 3.42 (chapter 3 verse 42) it is stated that:

"Now I would like that all of you worship Me by the
performance of a Rajasuya sacrifice and a horse sacrifice."

Why would lord Kalki accept an offering in which an animal is killed?